# Is there a way to create .doc files in PHP like one would use TCPDF to create pdf?

Tags: php, html

I've already got the functionality to print pdf reports and bills in my application, but now I need to also be able to export in .doc format. I'm using TCPDF's writeHTML function to write and format the pdf files, and I was wondering if there's a way to do the same for .doc files.

Comment: PHPWord - http://phpword.codeplex.com/ - can create .docx files (the default format for MS Word 2007 and 2010)

Comment: If you're planning on making invoices and bills in DOC format, I'll advice against it. DOC is easily changeable, someone will easily be able to fabricate a report of yours.

Comment: Easiest way is to simply produce an RTF file and serve it up as a .doc.

Comment: Well I won't question my manager's decision but we're only gonna use the .doc functions internally. I personally think bills and invoices in doc are a bad idea as well, but hey, it's the manager's job to manage and mine to make stuff happen when people click on things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward. A .doc file can just contain HTML. If you pass along the Word header, you can just start printing HTML. So, for example:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
print "<table border=\"1\"><tr><td><b>field1</b></td><td><b>field2</b></td></tr>";
print "<tr><td>value1 </td><td bgcolor=\"#137799\">value2 in blue cell bakground</td></tr></table>";
?>
```

Source: [here](http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/php-create-word-document-t65376.html) (verified it to be working).

Comment: Thanks, I was aware you could just print doc files in php but i wasn't sure you can just stick html in it. will try to see how it works

Comment: Not strictly true.... a "real" .doc file cannot contain html. However, MS word is pretty forgiving, detects that you're lying to it, and loads the html anyway.

Comment: I have just one question to ask tho, when I enter the exact thing you posted it prompts me to save or open a php file, can I have it create a .doc file instead (the php file contains the code, if that helps) Nevermind, i found the answer in the forum thread you linked. many thanks.

Comment: @Bogdan using the `Content-Disposition` header should take care of that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. one more question, if I may: is there any way to set margins and things like that for the document?